# How to determine bits, bytes and memory cells amount?

Tags: memory

1) How many memory cells are there in `"4K x 8"` memory?

2) How many words can be stored in it?

3) How many bits are there in every word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "4K x 8" notation indicates memory organization: it means there are 4096 memory locations, each containing 8 bits. I'll *assume* the word size is `4` bytes (word size varies across architectures, typical choices include `1`, `2`, `4`, and `8` bytes). To answer your questions:

1. There are `4096` (which is what 4K tells you) memory  locations, with each cell storing `8` bits (which is what x8 tells you).
2. We can store `1024` words (`1024=4096/4`) because one word (of size `32` bits) fits into `4` cells (`4=32/8`).
3. In every word there are `32` bits (`32=4*8`).

Comment: Can you explain how have you decided that one word is 32 bits too?

Comment: I assumed---as I've now pointed out in the answer. I don't think you can infer the word size from the data you gave us.

Comment: Thanks, I generally understood your answer but in question word size hasn't been specified.

Comment: Hm, then when answering you should probably specify that you assumed the word size to be 4 bytes. (Even better would be to enquire with the author of the question.)